# How to make process B running only while Process A is alive

Tags: c++, windows, waitforsingleobject

I have a process A that starts another process B.
Currently process B waits for a signal(WaitForSingleObject) that is signaled by the process'A ' before exiting and once the signal is set the process B exits.
However when Process A terminates or crashes unexpectedly I end up with process B still running.
How can I make B wait for the signal indefinitely except when the Process A has crashed? 
In other words ..  Process B should stay alive only till Process A is running.
thanks

Comment: You could hand process B a reference to process A and have it poll it every few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WaitForSingleObject` on process A's process handle; it will signal when A dies.

One other way of doing it is to attach B to A as a debugger. Then you will get an event when the process has exited, and can exit in perfect synchronization.

Comment: Thanks .. how can i pass the process A handle to  process B ?

Comment: Process B can use `OpenProcess` to get a waitable handle. Process B will need to know how to find process A though; you could pass the PID in as a command line parameter (easiest). Otherwise Process B could use `FindWindow` or similar.

Comment: Thanks @tenfour I was able to use the above approach to address the problem .

Answer (score 0):

When starting `B`, pass it the pid of A. In `B`, start a new thread that actively checks whether that pid corresponds to a running `A`. When this no longer holds, exit.

Comment: Thanks , but what if A exited but the system allocated the same pid to a different process ?

Comment: @user1622250 that's why you also check the name, not just the pid.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have tcp sockets sending heartbeat messages between the two processes and you could even extend that to where A and B are on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to use a [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than an event.  If process A exits, the mutex will be considered abandoned and process B's wait on the mutex will be satisfied.

Alternatively, you could give B a handle to process A and have it wait on both the event and the handle to process A.  If you use this approach, the best way for B to get a handle to A is by inheritance; use DuplicateHandle (with bInheritHandle set to TRUE) in process A to convert the pseudohandle returned by GetCurrentProcess into a real handle.  Pass the value of the handle to process B on the command line or in an environment variable.